# How to add mp3 files to mongodb compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to import audio files to mongodb on my windows machine using windows power shell. Can anyone please help me in doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using GridFS. simply do `mongofiles.exe -d audioschema put path\to\file.mp3` from power shell.

Ensure that you have added mongodb bin folder to environment variables path.